# Heroku: NameError: uninitialized constant User::AvatarUploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, carrierwave

I have been trying to google this question for a while and am not finding any answers.

For some reason, my app works fine when I run on localhost but not when I deploy to heroku.

I think the relevant gems/services are Heroku, CarrierWave, and possibly Devise & Fog-AWS.

```
rails aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant User::AvatarUploader
/app/app/models/user.rb:6:in `<class:User>'
/app/app/models/user.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:12:in `block in loading'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:149:in `exclusive'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:11:in `loading'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:269:in `const_get'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:269:in `block in constantize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `inject'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:267:in `constantize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.2/lib/devise.rb:315:in `get'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:83:in `to'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:78:in `modules'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:95:in `routes'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:162:in `default_used_route'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.2/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.2/lib/devise.rb:345:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.2/lib/devise.rb:345:in `add_mapping'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:243:in `block in devise_for'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:242:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.4.2/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:242:in `devise_for'
/app/config/routes.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:424:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:424:in `eval_block'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:406:in `draw'
/app/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:55:in `block in load_paths'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:55:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:55:in `load_paths'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:18:in `reload!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:41:in `block in updater'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.2/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:81:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:42:in `updater'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:31:in `execute_if_updated'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:128:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
/app/config/environment.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/application.rb:329:in `require_environment!'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/application.rb:445:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:21:in `block in perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:18:in `perform'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
/app/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/app/bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',        '5.1.2'
gem 'bcrypt',       '3.1.11'

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.7'
gem 'puma',         '3.9.1'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier',     '3.2.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.2'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.3.1'
gem 'turbolinks',   '5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.7.0'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.1.6'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'

gem 'ice_cube'
gem 'chronic'
# [START omniauth]
gem 'devise'
gem "omniauth"
gem "omniauth-google-oauth2"
gem 'omniauth-google'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'

# [END omniauth]
gem 'dotenv-rails'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug',  '9.0.6', platform: :mri
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
  gem 'rspec-rails'

end
group :development, :test, :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.5.1'
  gem 'listen',                '3.0.8'
  gem 'spring',                '2.0.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '1.0.2'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.14'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.13.0'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.4'
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'rspec-core'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :production do
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]


#URL Gems
gem "validate_url"
gem 'metainspector'

#Avatars
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.0'
gem 'rmagick', '~> 2.0'
gem "mini_magick"

gem 'fog-aws'
```

user.rb:

```
require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
class User < ApplicationRecord

  devise :rememberable, :trackable,
         :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: %i[google_oauth2]
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
```

application.rb

```
require 'carrierwave'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.1
    config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'uploaders', '*.rb')]
```

carrierwave.rb:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  # Use local storage if in development or test
  if Rails.env.test? or Rails.env.cucumber?
    CarrierWave.configure do |config|
      config.storage = :file
      config.enable_processing = false
    end
  end

  # Use AWS storage if in production
  if Rails.env.production?
    CarrierWave.configure do |config|
      config.storage = :fog
    end
  end
  config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'                        # required
  config.fog_credentials = {
      provider:              'AWS',                        # required
      aws_access_key_id:     ENV['S3_KEY'],                        # required
      aws_secret_access_key: ENV['S3_SECRET'],                        # required
      region:                'us-east-2',                  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
  }
  config.fog_directory  = ENV['S3_BUCKET']                                   # required
  config.fog_public     = false                                                 # optional, defaults to true
  config.fog_attributes = { cache_control: "public, max-age=315576000" } # optional, defaults to {}
end

# config/initializers/carrierwave.rb

    module CarrierWave
      module MiniMagick
        def quality(percentage)
          manipulate! do |img|
            img.quality(percentage.to_s)
            img = yield(img) if block_given?
            img
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

avatar_uploader.rb:

```
class AvatarUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  # include CarrierWave::RMagick
   include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  #storage :file
  storage :fog
  process resize_to_fill: [60, 60]
  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  # def default_url(*args)
  #   # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
  #   # ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))
  #
  #   "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  # end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
   process scale: [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
   version :thumb do
     process resize_to_fit: [50, 50]
   end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  # def extension_whitelist
  #   %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  # end

  # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
  # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
   process :convert => 'png'
   def filename
     super.chomp(File.extname(super)) + '.png' if original_filename
   end
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How about you show `AvatarUploader`?

Comment: Something thinks that your AvatarUploader class is inside a User module. That seems wrong to me. Search your code for occurrences of AvatarUploader and see what might be causing that behavior.

Comment: @jvillian @moveson Just added my `AvatarUploader` file, which is the only file where AvatarUploader occurs, aside from my user.rb `mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader`

Comment: Predictably, the error disappears when I remove `mount_uploader` from my user.rb file. But of course, so does the functionality.

Comment: Yup, `app/uploaders/avatar_uploader.rb`. Should it be different..?

Comment: have you restarted your rails app since you generated the AvatarUploader?

Comment: Perhaps try `::AvatarUploader` in your `User` model. That should force the constant look up to start in the global namespace.

Comment: This gives me a new error `load_missing_constant': Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant User (RuntimeError)
`

Comment: @amingilani yes

Answer (score 0):

On the `application.rb` add this line `require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'` from `user.rb`, so after added this line to `application.rb` then it will look like something

```
require 'rails/all'
require 'carrierwave'
require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
```

actually, this the way which works for me after error

> NameError: uninitialized constant User::AvatarUploader

then updated like this.

Comment: If you are using spring gem then you have to "restart" it by changing `config/application.rb`

Comment: ***Optional*** have migrated the pending migration to the Heroku?

Comment: New error! `NameError: uninitialized constant CarrierWave::Storage::Fog`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so some changes I made to solve this issue:

config/environment.rb :

```
require 'carrierwave'
require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
```

carrierwave.rb:

```
 config.fog_credentials = {
      provider:              'AWS',                        # required
      aws_access_key_id:     ENV['S3_KEY'],                        # required
      aws_secret_access_key: ENV['S3_SECRET'],                        # required
      region:                'us-east-2',                  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
  }
  config.storage = :fog #must go after credentials
```

Note: It is important for `config.storage` to go after `config.fog.credentials`!

Then I set `S3_KEY` `S3_SECRET` in terminal with

`heroku config:set S3_KEY=********* S3_SECRET=*******`

and it worked!

Comment: This was basic recommendations, you should not have been posting a question for this

Comment: Why didn't you recommend them then? This answer is the solution to `NameError: uninitialized constant CarrierWave::Storage::Fog` error and was scraped from multiple sources.

Comment: I have been working with Ruby on Rails for over a year and never did I learn that putting require statements in `config/environment.rb` loads all of the specified files before the app launches